# C++ Qt QTableWidgetItem causes crash

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qstring, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget called tw_topic. It's not empty. In another function I need the text of the items.

Code :

```
for(int i = ui->tw_topic->rowCount(); i >= 0; i--)
{
    //should return the first item of the first column
    const QString itm = ui->tw_topic->item(i, 0)->text();
    //Here I will do some other stuff...
}
```

Somehow it crashes at the point where itm gets initialized and I dont know why.

Comment: one of `ui, tw_topic` or what is returned by `item(i, 0)` is `NULL` for some reason. Try breaking down the statement in to single steps. You will find out which one is NULL. Or debug and try stepping in to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the for loop was the problem.

It should look like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < ui->tw_topic->rowCount(); i++)
{ 
    // stuff 
}
```

If `i` is `ui->tw_topic` last row it'll crash.

Comment: Or, if for anything, you want to keep the backwards (for example, deleting items is easier backwards, so you dont have to mess with index changes ) `for(int i = ui->tw_topic->rowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`